# Strange service permission behaviour

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

I've got a SendActivity, that launches an UploadService.

The problem happens when i let the SendActivity then immediately starts another activity and finishes itself. The UploadService gets the file, that it's supposed to upload, from a content provider. But when the SendActivity isn't i the foreground in the moment the service tries to access the file through the provider I get a "Permission Denial" although the permission is listed in my manifest.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A24669 from pid=28913, uid=10441 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:646)
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are passing a `Uri` from `SendActivity` to `UploadService`. `SendActivity` perhaps has rights to read that content, but `UploadService` does not.

In the `Intent` used to start `UploadService`, call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` to transfer read access from `SendActivity` to `UploadService`, and see if that helps. If it does not, then perhaps `SendActivity` *also* does not have read access, in which case you would need to look at how you are getting the `Uri` in the first place.